# Ошибка Traceback (most recent call last) python

Tags: python, discord.py, discord, авторизация

Не могу понять в чем проблема делал бота для дискорда
вот код:

```
import discord
import os
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands

sys.setrecursionlimit(n)
intents = discord.Intents.all()
Bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".", intents=intents)
BOT_TOKEN = "<МОЙ ТОКЕН>"


@Bot.slash_command(description="Добавление эмодзи")
async def addreaction(ctx, messege_id,reaction):
    proverka = await ctx.fetch_message(messege_id)
    await proverka.add_reaction(reaction)
    emb = discord.Embed(title="Эмодзи успешно добавлено", color=0x272727)
    await ctx.response_send_message(embed=emb)


Bot.run(BOT_TOKEN)
```

вот сама ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\suhro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 418, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route("GET", "/users/@me"))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\suhro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 371, in request
    raise HTTPException(response, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 401 Unauthorized (error code: 0): 401: Unauthorized

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Discrod bot Popytka 1\main.py", line 16, in <module>
    Bot.run (BOT_TOKEN)
  File "C:\Users\suhro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 717, in run
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\suhro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 696, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\suhro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 659, in start
    await self.login(token)
  File "C:\Users\suhro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 515, in login
    data = await self.http.static_login(token.strip())
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\suhro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 422, in static_login
    raise LoginFailure("Improper token has been passed.") from exc
discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.
```

Comment: Ошибка сообщает, что токен неверный

Comment: И, кстати, публикуя пример кода стоит скрывать все токены, пароли и т.п. Иначе кто-нибудь может ими воспользоваться.